# how can you overwrite a file line with zeros

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I am trying to find the best way to overwrite a file with zeros; every character in the file will be replaced by 0.

currently I have this working:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput('/path/to/file', inplace =1):
    for x in line:
        x = 0
```

But this looks very inefficient; is there a better way to do it?

Comment: By `0` do you mean `0x00` byte or the ascii character `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the characters one by one, I prefer to create a new file with the same name and same size:

Obtaining size of current file:

```
>>> file_info = os.stat("/path/to/file")
>>> size = file_info.st_size
```

Creating another file containing `0x00` with the same size:

```
>>> f = open("/path/to/file", "w")
>>> f.seek(size  - 1)
>>> f.write("\x00")
>>> f.close()
>>>
```

*I assumed by `0`, you meant `0x00` byte value*

Answer (score 1):

Use regex replacement, maybe?

```
import re
path = "test.txt"
f = open(path, "r")
data = re.sub(".", "0", f.read())
f.close()
f = open(path, "w")
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex is probably cleaner, but here is a solution using `fileinput`:

```
import fileinput
import sys
for line in fileinput.FileInput('/path/to/file', inplace=True):
    line = '0' * len(line)
    sys.stdout.write(line + "\n")
```

Note, if you use the `print` function, extra newlines will be added - so I used `sys.stdout.write`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput('/path/to/file', inplace =1):
    print len(line)*'0'
```